# App crashes after taking photo with Android camera app in different orientation than it was started

Tags: android

My app has a simple taking photo feature. User presses button, app launches camera app via MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. User captures a new photo, presses done, my app is restarted, the image is resized and assigned to an ImageView. Everything seems to be working fine except one case: if user changes the phone orientation during the process of taking a new photo. For example, if user goes to the camera app in portrait mode, rotate the device, take a picture in a landscape mode and then presses done in the camera app, my app crashes with:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

This is the method that causes the crash:

```
 takenImage = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth
                    (fullSizeImage, mProductImageView.getWidth() / 100 * 50);
```

BitmapScaler.java

```
public static Bitmap scaleToFitWidth(Bitmap b, int width)
    {
        float factor = width / (float) b.getWidth();
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, (int) (b.getHeight() * factor), true);
    }
```

At the same time if user captures photo in a different orientation but goes back to the original orientation before pressing done, the app is restored correctly. The same issue applies when user selects an existing image from the library instead of taking a new photo.

This is the hole bunch of code handling the above feature:

```
    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
public void pickPhotoFromGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_CODE);
    }
}

@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
public void onLaunchCamera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photoFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
    photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);

    mPicUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            ProductContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPicUri);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

public File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
    }
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    /* User chose to take a new photo */
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            File takenPhoto = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);
            Bitmap fullSizeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(takenPhoto.getAbsolutePath());
            // RESIZE BITMAP
            takenImage = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth
                    (fullSizeImage, mProductImageView.getWidth() / 100 * 50);
        } else { // Result was a failure
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_picture_taken),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /* User chose to take an an existing photo from the gallery */
    else if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPicUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap fullSizeImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap
                        (getContentResolver(), mPicUri);

                takenImage = BitmapScaler.scaleToFitWidth
                        (fullSizeImage, mProductImageView.getWidth() / 100 * 60);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    mProductImageView.setImageBitmap(takenImage); }
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable the app-restart on rotate in your manifest? Are you using a fragment? The null pointer means that when the screen rotates, the view is being restarted and the Bitmap,b, is null.

Comment: The app has to allow rotation. I can't disable it. No fragments are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a configuration change, by default, your activity is destroyed and recreated, if your activity is visible. So, what happens in your scenario is:

- Your activity exists, in portrait orientation
- You call `startActivityForResult()` with an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`
- The camera app's activity comes to the foreground
- The user rotates the screen to landscape, but your activity is not affected yet, as it is not visible
- The user takes a picture using whatever camera app handle your `Intent`
- The user confirms the picture (assuming the camera app offers such a confirmation step)
- The camera activity is destroyed
- Your activity is becoming visible and the orientation changed (portrait to landscape), so your activity is destroyed and recreated
- Your `onActivityResult()` is being called

At that point, your crash is because `mProductImageView` is `null`. You need to make sure that this field gets initialized before trying to use it. So, for example, you could initialize it in `onCreate()` of the activity.

Comment: It is initialized in the onCreate(). Still the issue persists.

Comment: When activity rotation is disabled everything is working fine.  I also tried to set a hardcoded width value (i.e. without any mProductImageView references), it won't help too.

Comment: @Potato: You cannot get a `NullPointerException` if you are not calling some method on `null`. You are crashing somewhere else, if you got rid of the `mProductImageView` references.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the image path. I noticed this log way above the NullPointerException. Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myname.inventoryapp/files/Pictures/InventoryApp/1526996986712.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Potato: Add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` and see if that helps.

Comment: Flag added. No success, unfortunately.

Comment: When activity rotation is disabled everything is working fine. Then this is part of the problem, the rotation is destroying the view and recreating a rotated view. We have to handle this to fix the problem.

Comment: The problem is in some cases onActitvityResult() is called before(!!!) onCreate(). In this case when you leave the activity, rotate the device and goes back to Activity ImageView is redrawn at the time onActitvityResult is called so it make sense to use getWidth() method in onActitvityResult() and not on onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

if you are using crop image library in calling camera intent or open gallery intent -com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity,
solution of the problem, you need to add it in the manifest-

```
      <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```